# Can`t instantiate class using IOC contatiner laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ioc-container

I`m trying to get instanse of my class using dependency injection.
This class has own service provider that registered in app.php

```
 class Something
 {
      private $variable;

      public function __construct(string $variable)
      {
          $this->variable = $variable; 
      }
 }
```

this is service provider

```
class SomethingServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {

    }


    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('Something', function () {
            return new Something( 'test');
        });
    }
}
```

and when I try to use this class instance in controller...

```
class TestController extends AppBaseController
{
    public function __construct(Something $something)
    {
        $this->something = $something;
    }
...
```

I got error:

> "Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ string $variable ]]
>   in class Something at
>   Container->unresolvablePrimitive(object(ReflectionParameter)) in
>   Container.php (line 848) "

Comment: In addition to other answers, be sure to add this service provider in your config/app.php so that it can be loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `YourServiceProvider::__construct` accepts a non-typed `$app` instance. This means that Laravel cannot automatically resolve it. Try typing it; `public function __construct(Application $app)` with the proper use-statement.

More: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container#automatic-injection

Comment: Not sure what I'm missing here. There's no constructor in the service provider

Answer (score 0):

When you register something to be injected you need to use the fully qualified class name:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton(Something::class, function () {
        return new Something( 'test');
    });
}
```

Otherwise Laravel will try to automatically inject something which implies that it will try to inject the dependencies of `Something` first and then determine that this is a string and fail.